# Php create folder on specific path

Tags: php

I need to create folder on specific path.

This is my path where i need to create folder

```
/media/catalog/product
```

all new created folders must be in product folder

my script with code is on this path

```
/api
```

I tried with this but do not work

```
//this part works
$firstFolderName = $image_name_no_exstension[0];
$secondFolderName = $image_name_no_exstension[1];

// this part do not work
if (!is_dir('/media/catalog/product/'.$firstFolderName )) {
    mkdir("/media/catalog/product/".$firstFolderName, 0777, true);
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the user running the `php` (usually called www-data) process must have write privilege to that directory

Comment: and further you are using absolute paths. I am not really good at this, but I think you should use relative paths.

Comment: What does "not work mean"? What error do you get? Are you sure you have the permissions to create the directory?

Comment: it works if i want to create directory on same path of my script. example  mkdir("test", 0777, true);
}

Comment: as it Looks. u are writing for Magento. U Should check the permissions as @dimlucas said.

Comment: /media/catalog/product
all of these folders have 777 permission. yes i am writing for magento

Comment: imo, you are not doing anything wrong - except you need to validate the `$firstFolderName` variable. i.e. `trim($firstFolderName, '/');` and probably convert to lowercase? I would define the `'/media/catalog/product/'` path as a configuration item. The directory must be outside of the web root for security. imo, Never use relative filepaths in PHP scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i said, problem is not in permissions
i resolve problem with    `dirname(__FILE__)`

code:

```
    if (!is_dir(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../media/catalog/product/' . $firstFolderName)) {
                mkdir(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../media/catalog/product/' . $firstFolderName, 0777, true);
            } else {
                mkdir(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../media/catalog/product/' . $firstFolderName . '/' . $secondFolderName, 0777, true);
            }

....

move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, dirname(__FILE__) . '/../media/catalog/product/' . $firstFolderName . '/' . $secondFolderName . '/' . $file_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worked for me.

```
function create_directory($path, $mode = 0777, $recursive = true) {
    if(file_exists($path)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      echo("Unable to create folder");
    }
    return mkdir($path, $mode, $recursive);
}

create_directory('path/to/directory');
```

It returns true if already exists or is successfully created. Else it returns false.